# ¿Porque mis variables no mantienen su valor?

Tags: java, poo

estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto con un lector de huellas digitales(ZKteco), una de sus funciones principales es la de mandarle un parámetro(El ID en este caso) para que este haga una búsqueda a una base de datos, dentro de esta búsqueda trae un dato tipo blob, el cual es la plantilla de la huella digital del usuario con la que fue registrada, una vez tenga esta plantilla el programa la agrega a la memoria, ya estando en la memoria utilizo una función de la librería del lector de huellas para hacer una comparación con esa plantilla y con otra que se genera al momento que el usuario coloque su huella en el lector, esta es la función:

```
 int[] fid = new int[1];
 int[] score = new int [1];

 //template: Plantilla de huella digital
 //fid: El ID del usuario
 //score: El puntaje de comparación

 int ret = FingerprintSensorEx.DBIdentify(mhDB,template,fid,score);

 /*DBIdentify Esta función se utiliza para realizar una comparación 1: N.
 Compara la huella con las otras huellas ya registradas antes*/
```

El tema es el siguiente, para hacer la búsqueda, el usuario tiene que ingresar su ID, el cual le pido en un inputdialog, la función es la siguiente:

(Es importante mencionar que esta función se encuentra en una clase llamada Busqueda)

```
  public void buscar( String nombre,Blob bytesImagen,Long mhDB,byte[] template) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException{
    
  Connection con = connect();
  int ret;
  Image rpta=null;
  
String clave = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa la clave de usuario: ");
if(clave!=null){
    try{
    PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM usuariosconhuellas WHERE idusuariosConHuellas LIKE '%"+clave+"%'");
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        
    idEnMemoria = rs.getInt("idusuariosConHuellas");//udEnMemoria es una variable instanciada.
    bytesImagen = rs.getBlob("Huella");
    rpta = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(bytesImagen.getBinaryStream());

    setID(idEnMemoria);//Mando el ID a la función seID
    //Creamos la imagen en disco:
  ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) rpta, "bmp", new File("C:\\Users\\manuel.vargas\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\PruebaZFK\\copia_Huella.bmp"));

  int[] TamañoPlantilla = new int[1];
  TamañoPlantilla[0] = 2048;
  byte[] plantillaDevuelta = new byte[2048];

  //Establecemos la ruta en donde creamos la imagen en disco:
  String ruta = "C:\\Users\\manuel.vargas\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\PruebaZFK\\copia_Huella.bmp"; 
  ret = FingerprintSensorEx.ExtractFromImage( mhDB, ruta, 500, plantillaDevuelta, TamañoPlantilla);     //Registramos la imagen 
  if(ret==0){//Si ret=0 significa que todo es corecto, entonces procedemos a registrar en memoria
 
  ret = FingerprintSensorEx.DBAdd( mhDB, idEnMemoria, plantillaDevuelta);//Guardamos la plantilla en memoria
  }

  ret = FingerprintSensorEx.DBCount(mhDB);//DbCount nos dice cuantos usuarios existen en memoria.
  if(ret>=0){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ret + " Usuarios en meoria");//Aquí nos muestra cuantos usuarios tenemos en memoria por medio de un mensaje en pantalla


  }else{//Si ret es menor a 0 significa que algo salio mal, y lo mostramos en el siguiente mensaje:
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocurrio un error al contar los usuarios en memoria: " + ret);
  }

                    
  con.close();//Cerramos la conexión

                    }else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"USUARIO NO ENCONTRADO!","ERROR DE OPERACIÓN",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    //borrarTodo(mhDB);
                    prueba prueba = new prueba();
                    ret = FingerprintSensorEx.DBCount(mhDB);
                    if(ret>0){
                    prueba.Borrar(idEnMemoria,mhDB);
                    }
                    con.close();}

}catch (Exception e){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);}
}
}
```

Seguido de esa función, se lanza una función que se llama identificación:

```
 public void identificación(){
  int ret = FingerprintSensorEx.DBCount(mhDB);
  
    if(ret>0){
    int[] fid = new int[1];
                if(bRegister)//bRegister es un booleanos que es true unicamente para registrar usuarios
            {
                enroll_idx = 0;
                bRegister = false;
            }
            if(!bIdentify)
            {
                bIdentify = true;//Pasamos bIdentify a true para ejecutar nuestra siguiente función.
            }                               
 //Lo decimos al usuario por medio de un mensaje en pantalla que coleque su dedo en el lector:
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor, pon tu dedo en el lector.","VERIFICACIÓN",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

  } else{bIdentify = false;}
}
```

Aquí es donde entramos a la función identificarUsuario que la tengo en una clase llamada Identificación, y es aquí donde comienza el problema, la clase es la siguiente:

```
 public void identificarUsuario(long mhDB,byte[] template,Blob foto1,JButton btnFoto,JButton btnImg) throws InterruptedException, IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
Busqueda buc = new Busqueda();
prueba prueba = new prueba();

                int[] fid = new int[1];
                int[] score = new int [1];
                int ret = FingerprintSensorEx.DBIdentify(mhDB,
                                            template/*Plantilla de huella digital*/,
                                            fid/*El ID del usuario*/,
                                            score/*El puntaje de comparación*/);/*DBIdentify Esta función se utiliza para realizar una comparación 1: N.
                                    Compara la huella con las otras huellas ya registradas antes*/
                if (ret == 0)
                {
                  
                    buc.busqueda(fid,foto1,btnFoto,score);/*Manda los parametros a la función búsqueda
                    para mostrar la información del usuario en pantalla*/
      
                    int i = Integer.parseInt(buc.id);//Parseamos el id del usuario y lo movemos a la variable i
                     prueba.Borrar(i,mhDB);/*Ese valor lo mandamos a la función borrar para proceder a eliminar al usuario
                     de la memoria*/
                   Thread.sleep(5*1000);
                    btnFoto.setIcon(null);
                    btnImg.setIcon(null);
                    
      
                }
                else //Si la identificación falla salta ese else
                    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Verificación fallida, error: " + ret +"\nPor favor, Intentelo de nuevo","VERIFICACIÓN FALLIDA",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    //Parseamos el id del usuario y lo movemos a la variable i
                    //int i = Integer.parseInt(buc.idEnMemoria);
                     prueba.Borrar(buc.getID(),mhDB);
                    }

}
```

Al momento que la identificación falla, quiero que borre al usuario que tiene en pantalla, la  función que lo borra se llama borrar y esta en mi Jframe llamado prueba, la función es la siguiente:

```
 public void Borrar(int i,long mhDB) throws InterruptedException{
   int ret;
 
   //En el parametro i recibimos el ID del usuario
   
    ret = FingerprintSensorEx.DBDel(mhDB, i);//Esta linea se encarga de borrar al usuario, que en este caso
    //El usuario es i.
    
    
    if(ret!=0){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Error al intentar borrar usuarios de memoria: " + ret);
    }
    
}
```

Como consigo el parámetro del ID del usuario seguro se preguntan, bueno, en la clase búsqueda tengo la variable de instancia:

```
  int idEnMemoria;
```

y al momento de hacer la búsqueda ella recibe el id del usuario que encuentra en la base de datos, esa id la mando a una función con la siguiente línea de código:

```
   setID(idEnMemoria);//Mando el ID a la función seID
```

La función a donde mando ese parámetro es esta:

```
 public void setID(int id){
 this.idEnMemoria=id;
```

}

Una vez esa función tenga mi ID al momento de que la identificación del usuario falla y entra el else de la función identificarUsuario y se ejecuta esta línea:

```
 prueba.Borrar(buc.getID(),mhDB);
```

en buc.getID() se supone que tengo el ID del usuario, este public int se encuentra en la clase Búsqueda, y es el siguiente:

```
 public int getID(){
 return idEnMemoria;
 }
```

El problema, es que nunca me retorna la ID que almacena la variable de instancia idEnMemoria, siempre me retorna 0, ya intente esto de todas maneras, incluso heredando la clase, o mandando la variable de la siguiente manera:

```
      Busqueda buc = new Busqueda();
             prueba.Borrar(buc.idEnMemoria,mhDB);
```

Alguien sabe que pasa? he usado debug en NetBeans y cuando inicia la primera función la variable tiene el valor del id. Ejemplo idEnMemoria=16;
pero al momento de que se ejecuta la línea para borrar llega la función siendo 0.
Agradecería mucho su ayuda.!

Dejo la siguiente foto en donde se muestra que la variable tiene un valor:

[image: La variable tiene 27 de valor]

Por si no quedo muy claro, aquí dejo algunos screenShots, al momento de hacer la búsqueda, la variable idEnMemoria obtiene como valor el ID del usuario:

[image: idEnMemoria]

Pero cuando ejecuto la función de identificación, y la identificación falla, se ejecuta un else, el cual llama a la función borrar y a esa función le mando como parámetro IdEnMemoria, pero al momento de llamar a la variable idEnMemoria, esta ya es 0 o nula:

[image: las funciones están en clases diferentes.]

Comment: Has puesto un código kilométrico. ¿Podrías señalar dónde está el problema exactamente? Gracias.

Comment: @A.Cedano cuando escribo:  prueba.Borrar(buc.getID(),mhDB); Estoy mandando como parámetro buc.getID() a la función borrar, el problema esta que ese parámetro debe tener un valor y al momento de cuando llega a la función borrar llego siendo 0 o nulo.

Comment: ¿Y lo probaste antes de enviarlo? ¿Qué valor tiene antes de enviarlo?

Comment: @A.Cedano Si, tiene la variable tiene un valor, pero luego vuelve a ser 0, deje una imagen adjunta donde se muestra que tiene un valor.
La puse al final de la pregunta.

Comment: Ya, pero ahí la variable es otra: `idEnMemoria`. Síguele la pista a `idEnMemoria`, supongo que en alguna parte la asignas a `buc` pero antes de eso el dato se pierde. El problema es que entre tanto código es complicado analizar. Simplemente en el debug síguele la pista a la variable y descubrirás dónde se pierde.

Comment: Has probado si `rs.getInt("idusuariosConHuellas");` retorna correctamente un valor que deseas que no sea null o 0 ?.. Entre tanto código es el único que se le asigna a tu `idEnMemoria`

Comment: por favor siempre llama con.close() dentro de un finally o mejor aun usa un try(Connection con = ...) { } 
Es muy grave no cerrar conexiones.

Comment: @AminM Todas mis funciones que conectan a base de datos al final se cierran con con.close()

Comment: @Richard Si amigo, lo he probado con el debug y al momento de hacer la búsqueda todas las variables obtienen un valor, incluso todas las funciones sirven correctamente, el único problema que tengo, como lo mencione, es cuando la comparación no se hace correctamente, ya que cuando eso pasa, la función de comparación entra en un else, que al final llama a otra función donde limpia la memoria, a esa función le mando un parámetro y ese parámetro debería ser el ID del usuario, que se almacena en idEnMemoria, pero cuando mando esa variable a la función es 0.

Comment: llamar con.close() en insuficiente. Hay que hacerlo dentro de un FINALLY.. si no, si hay una excepción puede no cerrarse la conexion. En aplicaciones de verdad eso puede crear una fuga de recursos que puede resultar en lentitud o en casos extremos que se cuelgue. Tu ejemplo aca, no es correcto. Usa FINALLY o mejor try-with-resources.

Comment: @AminM gracias por el consejo amigo, Voy a concentrarme en ello.